# Login some users as root with SSH and LDAP

Tags: ssh, ldap, users, public-key

I have a SSH + LDAP installation with users public keys stored in LDAP.

I want that when some user in a list (configured into server) do a ssh connection with `ssh user@server` always log in as `root`. `user` user not exists on server, only on LDAP.

Now I have working this steps if I have configured my LDAP `uid` as `root` and ssh connection is `ssh root@server`.

But I need to login with `ssh user@server`.

Is SSH able to do this map?

*Moved from StackOverflow.*

Answer (score 0):

On the SSH server, try adding the following line to bottom of `/etc/passwd` for the ldap user:

`user:x:0:0::/root:/bin/bash`

(replace `user` with the ldap username)

This will map the username `user` to root. I know it works if you have a corresponding entry in the shadow file and log in using that type of auth. So hopefully will work without the shadow entry for LDAP.

Comment: Users should not exists on server, only on LDAP, and once checked public key, must be log in as root. Maybe is not possible.

Comment: With my answer the user does not really exist on the server. Is just a mapping to root.

Comment: Yes, but I need to configure the "virtual" user in `/etc/passwd`. I need some solution only LDAP dependent. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible the way you want :-)